# Access SQL Query Top 1 percent group by winsorizing

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, outliers

I need to find the 99th and 1th percentiles for a variable at each date. So far I have managed to do so but for the overall period, I would like to "loop" the following query (that does work) for each date (which is basic winsorizing) like a simple GROUP BY, but the latter does not work with TOP PERCENT)

```
SELECT Date,ID,Value, 
IIf(Value>[upper_threshold],[upper_threshold],IIf(Value<[lower_threshold],  
[lower_threshold],Value)) AS winsor_Value 
FROM MyTable,
(SELECT [lower_threshold], [upper_threshold] FROM (SELECT MAX(Value) AS 
lower_threshold FROM (SELECT TOP 1 PERCENT Value FROM MyTable ORDER BY   
Value))  AS t1, (SELECT MIN(Value) AS upper_threshold FROM (SELECT TOP 1 
PERCENT Value FROM MyTable ORDER BY Value DESC)));
```

My data looks like

[image]

I have 700 000 rows.

Thanks a lot

Comment: How about something like this: 

    SELECT top 1 percent (MAX)Value as Values from dbo.table Group By Date

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the following works in MS Access, but it is worth a try.  To get the value at the top 99%:

```
select t.date,
       (select min(t2.value)
        from (select top 1 percent t2.*
              from t as t2
              where t2.date = t.date
              order by t2.value desc
             ) as t2
       ) as percentile_99
from (select distinct date
      from t
     ) as t;
```

I do not know if MS Access scoping rules allow you to correlate a subquery more than one level deep.  If so the above approach should work for all the percentiles.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Gordon Linoff, unfortunately it does not work because the sub query
 (select top 1 percent t2.*
              from t as t2
              where t2.date = t.date
              order by t2.value desc
             ) as t2
keeps the 1% from the whole database (for example, it excludes some dates with "apparently no outliers".